# one instance of tkinter's entry get function isn't working while others around it work

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

In my code I have two `.get` functions referring to filled tkinter cells. They are entirely identical as far as I can tell. However, `new_comp_name.get()` works perfectly while `new_comp_email.get()` returns an empty value. A couple hours I give up and I thought I could get some help regarding this here. The code below is simplified but running it, I still encounter the same bizzar issue. I even resorted to restarting my computer but still, no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
def newc_popup():
    compviewFresh()
    newc_popup = Toplevel()
    newc_popup.title("New Company")
#-----------fetch options list from types DB
    connection = sqlite3.connect('companyDB99.db')
    ###### end of connection ####

    query="SELECT type_name as class FROM types"
    r_set=connection.execute(query);
    my_list = [r for r, in r_set] # create a  list 

    options = tk.StringVar(newc_popup)

    comptypeSELECT =tk.OptionMenu(newc_popup, options, *my_list)
    #om1.grid(row=2,column=5)

#-----------

    comp_name_label = Label(newc_popup, text="Company Name")
    comp_name_label.grid(row=1, column=0)

    new_comp_name = Entry(newc_popup, width=50)
    new_comp_name.grid(row=1, column=1)

    comp_email_label = Label(newc_popup, text="Email Address")
    comp_email_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

    new_comp_email = Entry(newc_popup, width=50)
    new_comp_email.grid(row=2, column=1)

    comptypeSELECT_lable = Entry(newc_popup, width=50)
    comptypeSELECT_lable.grid(row=2, column=1)

    comptypeSELECT.grid(row=3, column=1,)

    

    def addComp():
        compviewFresh()    
        connection = sqlite3.connect('companyDB99.db')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        print(new_comp_name.get())
        print(new_comp_email.get())

    addComp_btn = Button(newc_popup, text="Add Company", command=addComp)
    addComp_btn.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

Comment: You are putting `comptypeSELECT_lable` (which is an Entry, despite the name) in the same grid cell as `new_comp_email` - you're typing into the wrong field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `.get` is working fine. The problem is that you have two entries in the same place so you're not typing into the widget you think you're typing into.

Here's the problem:

```
new_comp_email.grid(row=2, column=1)
comptypeSELECT_lable.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

`comptypeSELECT_label` is an Entry, so when you think you are typing into `new_comp_email` you're actually typing into `comptypeSELECT_label` since it was added last and thus is on top of `new_comp_email`. Thus, `new_comp_email` is empty.

Comment: Thank you so much. I completely missed that. Works now. Cheers!!